# Weird behaviour initializing a numpy array of string data

Tags: python, numpy

I am having some seemingly trivial trouble with numpy when the array contains string data.  I have the following code:

```
my_array = numpy.empty([1, 2], dtype = str)
my_array[0, 0] = "Cat"
my_array[0, 1] = "Apple"
```

Now, when I print it with `print my_array[0, :]`, the response I get is `['C', 'A']`, which is clearly not the expected output of Cat and Apple.  Why is that, and how can I get the right output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Numpy requires string arrays to have a fixed maximum length.  When you create an empty array with `dtype=str`, it sets this maximum length to 1 by default.  You can see if you do `my_array.dtype`; it will show "|S1", meaning "one-character string".  Subsequent assignments into the array are truncated to fit this structure.

You can pass an explicit datatype with your maximum length by doing, e.g.:

```
my_array = numpy.empty([1, 2], dtype="S10")
```

The "S10" will create an array of length-10 strings.  You have to decide how big will be big enough to hold all the data you want to hold.

Comment: Once I update an element in the list (i.e `my_array[0] = 'hello'`), does that first element still have "10-characters worth" of memory allocated? Or is it now truly a `"S5" object? I assume not, since the `dtype` of a `numpy` array must be consistent across the entire array?

Comment: @jphollowed: Right, the size is fixed for the whole array, so if you initialize it as S10, it will still use up 10 bytes for each entry, even if the actual strings you store are smaller.

Comment: Why should I use this instead of `dtype=object` ? Is it faster ?

Comment: @Boern: Most operations will be faster on a string dtype than object dtype.  But in many cases using object dtype is okay if you don't care that much about speed.

Comment: Another example of shooting yourself in the leg with abstraction, especially when it comes to memory management. Not that I'd want to do everything in C, but it certainly illustrates the point. I also observed that printing an array of strings `print(arr)` can produce very different results from printing the elements `print(arr[:])`.

Comment: @orodbhen It's better to have abstracted and [leaked](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/) then never to have abstracted at all...

Comment: @profPlum Great article. Unfortunately, too many devs rely on abstraction without understanding what's underneath. Of course, it's not always practical to delve into the guts of things, but it's amazing how much easier problem solving gets after doing some good delving. Seems like I'm always forced to do it in the end.

Comment: @orodbhen Yes, this does happen and to some degree it is reasonable (not everyone needs to learn C to use python), but at the same time as he says it is worth starting with the guts so that you're prepared for when the abstractions leak. But at the end of the day without abstraction there's no way people would be able to make the cool software we have today with tools like C it would be a nightmare!

Comment: I had this problem, the default turned out to be S0.

Answer (score 22):

I got a "codec error" when I tried to use a non-ascii character with `dtype="S10"`

You also get an array with binary strings, which confused me.

I think it is better to use:

`my_array = numpy.empty([1, 2], dtype="<U10")`

Here 'U10' translates to "Unicode string of length 10; little endian format"

Comment: This would be an improved answer if it explained what `dtype = "<U10"` was.

Answer (score 12):

The numpy string array is limited by its fixed length (length 1 by default). If you're unsure what length you'll need for your strings in advance, you can use `dtype=object` and get arbitrary length strings for your data elements:

```
my_array = numpy.empty([1, 2], dtype=object)
```

I understand there may be efficiency drawbacks to this approach, but I don't have a good reference to support that.

Comment: are there any caveats (like slower speed) compared to, let's say "S10" ?

Answer (score 1):

in case of anyone who's new here, I guess there's another way to do this job for now, just need a little work:

```py
my_array = np.full([1, 2], "", dtype=np.object)
```

Use [np.full](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) instead of np.empty, and create the array with a empty string (type is object).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to initialize as follows:

```
my_array = np.array([["CAT","APPLE"],['','']], dtype=str)
```

In other words, first you write a regular array with what you want, then you turn it into a numpy array. However, this will fix your max string length to the length of the longest string at initialization. So if you were to add

```
my_array[1,0] = 'PINEAPPLE'
```

then the string stored would be 'PINEA'.

Answer (score 0):

What works best if you are doing a for loop is to start a list comprehension, which will allow you to allocate the right memory.

```
data = ['CAT', 'APPLE', 'CARROT']
my_array = [name for name in data]
```