# Change string values in numpy.array in certain indices

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create an array of strings, actually it is color value, for each value in another array. Logic is that for positive values should be one color, and for negatives another color.

I've tried this code snippet:

```
values = np.array([1, 2, -3, 4, 5])
color_values = np.array(['rgb(74,159,234)'] * len(values))
color_values[values < 0] = 'rgb(120,183,239)'
print(color_values)
```

But the problem is that new string values are truncating to length of previous value in array, so the result is:

```
['rgb(74,159,234)', 'rgb(74,159,234)', 'rgb(120,183,239', 'rgb(74,159,234)', 'rgb(74,159,234)']
```

THe third value is changed, but without last parethesis. I can rewrite code to achieve result I need but now I'm curious about why this happens.

I'm using `Python 3.6`, `numpy 1.14.2`

Comment: why to work with strings when we have `tuple`s or `numpy`-array triplet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13717700/9225671), str `numpy` arrays have a fixed length. They suggest specifying the data type when declaring the array.

You could try to add the datatype when declaring your array; set it to 16 chars (or more).

```
color_values = np.array(['rgb(74,159,234)'] * len(values), dtype='S16')
```

The rest of the lines should not need modification.