# How can I format this correctly so it refers correctly to an array value?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

window = Tk()

window.title("3 X 3 Game")

btarray = np.full((3, 3), "red", dtype='str')

arfinal = []

def clickbutton(arvalue):
    print (arvalue)
    if btarray[arvalue] == "red":
        btarray[arvalue] = "green"
    else:
        btarray[arvalue] = "red"

btn = Button(window, bg=btarray[0, 0], activebackground="blue", height=5, width=10, command= clickbutton("0, 0"))
```

the print returns 0, 0 which is the correct value for the first entry in the array, but I can't get it to accept this and change that array value, I get the error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I'm sure it has something to do with formatting and data types of the 0, 0 value in arvalue, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: ```bg=btarray[0][0]``` - is this what you mean?

Comment: it´s halting and giving the error on the line: if btarray[arvalue] == "red":, the bg=btarray[0, 0] is fine i think, because if i cut out all the bits about changing the array value, it opens a window with a red button, and it´s red because the 0, 0 array value is filled with "red" using the line: btarray = np.full((3, 3), "red", dtype='str')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

window = Tk()

window.title("3 X 3 Game")

btarray = np.full((3, 3), "red")
arfinal = []

def clickbutton(arvalue):
    a,b=arvalue.split(',')
    a,b=int(a),int(b)
    if btarray[a,b] == "red":
        btarray[a,b] = "green"
    else:
        btarray[a,b] = "red"
    print(btarray)

btn = Button(window, activebackground="blue", height=5, width=10, command= lambda: clickbutton("0, 0"))
btn.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes that´s almost it, fantastic! i say almost because for some reason it´s only putting "gre" in the value when it changes instead of "green", is this something i´m doing wrong in declaring the array?

Comment: @Rayne, to be honest, even I don't know what is going on

Comment: Well thanks for your help anyway, i´ll mark it as answered as i think you solved the problem i had with that split value line, it now correctly addresses the array value and changes it, but it´s just truncating it. It will be some random array issue, i´ll continue looking at it, thank you

Comment: @Rayne most welcome. If I find answer answer to this weird problem, I will let you know

Comment: i found it, i had to add "dtype="object" to the line where i declare the array, that stops it later truncating to 3 characters. on the downside, it doesn´t actually work, it´s not changing the colour of the button XD but looking at the print output it is correctly changing the value of the array to green

Answer (score 0):

Using clickbutton(0,0)  or clickbutton([0,0]) and then in the function use btarray[arvalue[0],arvalue[1]] will work?

Because right now you are passing a string as index not an Array of 2 values.

To solve your second issue about the string "Red" to "green" check this [Weird behaviour initializing a numpy array of string data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717554/weird-behaviour-initializing-a-numpy-array-of-string-data)